# How to open a Userform using a variable in the Name?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm trying to open UserForms based on the values of cells in one row of a sheet. There are 17 UserForms so I don't want to have to use 17 if statements for each form like this:

```
If ActiveCell.Value = 1 Then
     UserForm1.Show
End If
```

Is there a way that I can use a variable to show the forms?

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```vb
Dim i
Do
   If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
      Exit DO
   End If
   i = ActiveCell.Value
   UserForms("UserForm" & i).Show   ****THIS is what doesn't work
   ActiveCell.Offset(0,1).Select
Loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Paste the code from the link Harvey provided, then adjust this line in your code:

```
UserForms("UserForm" & i).Show  ****THIS is what doesn't work
```

to:

```
ShowAnyForm ("UserForm" & i)
```

That's a great link Harvey, I've bookmarked it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the often overlooked VBA.UserForms object. See [this link](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/showanyform.htm) which fully descibes what you need to do.

There's no point in my explaining it here.

Harvey

Comment: Harvey, Thanks for the response! I can't figure out exactly how to fit this into what I'm doing though. Which method I would use, syntax, etc.

Comment: In your code replace userforms  with VBA.UserForms and it might work. If not read the page I previously sent you and experiment. Show me what you tried.

Comment: The whole point of SO is for you to explain it HERE

Answer (score 1):

Get `UserForm` object defined by its string name

```
Function Form(Name As String) As Object
  Set Form = CallByName(UserForms, "Add", VbMethod, Name)
End Function

Sub Test()
  Dim strFormName As String
  strFormName = "UserForm1"  ' <-- replace by your lookup code instead
  Form(strFormName).Show
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never come accross the method mentioned by @Harvey (I like it, though) so would have used some sort of Select Case statement:

```
Select Case .Cells(1,1).Value
    Case 1:
        FormOne.Show
    Case 2:
        FormTwo.Show
    ' And so on and do forth...
    Case Else:
        MsgBox ("Invalid entry")
End Select
```

Simpler than 17 If statements, at least.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is this one:

```
Dim activeuf as Object
Set activeuf = UserForm & i
activeuf.show
```

Perhaps it will not work for the person who asked, but I'm sure it will help people who check this question in the future

Answer (score 0):

Here a "faster" code to open the form (Rao-Haribabu evolution):

```
Dim forMy
Set forMy = CallByName(UserForms, "Add", VbMethod, formName) ' formName is the form name to open
forMy.Show
```